# How should I handle deletion of objects in Object Relational Mapping

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, orm

I have had this confusion about how I handle the different lifecycle events of an Object where they are persisted in a database. I know this can vary with design, but I would like to know any standard / best practice which are followed in such cases.

Say I have a `User` class like this -

```
class User {
  int id;
  String name;
}
```

An object of this type represents a row in the database. The objects are accessed by multiple threads. So, how do you manage the object? What are its methods? How do you implement deletion of such an object?

Say there are two threads, A and B which are accessing the same user object.

```
// Thread A
User user = UserFactory.getUser(userId);

// Thread B
User user = UserFactory.getUser(userId)
user.delete(); // Or UserFactory.delete(userId)
```

Then what happens to the `user` object in thread A? Any clarification would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: You should not allow that.
You have to, somehow, block user if it is being used, or allow read-only operations if user is being accessed by other thread.

Comment: I was thinking that I should keep only one instance of this object. So, the threads will access the same object and any update operation will be synchronized. But what I cannot figure out is how I implement the deletion of a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then what happens to the user object in thread A? Any clarification would be very helpful.

Nothing. Of course that is probably your problem. What will happen if you try to persist in thread `A` after deletion is probably highly dependent on the ORM you are using but my guess assuming your using Hibernate is that it will fail trying to do an `UPDATE/DELETE` as the open `Session` in thread `A` does not know that the row is missing. This happens frequently.

**Notice** that thread `A` will always be able to mutate the user object freely with out error so long as it does not persist/delete. The error will only happen when you go persist/delete. In this case whoever is first persist/delete wins (no error).

People mitigate this problem in a variety of ways:

1. Silently swallow the exception and either reinsert the object or ignore
2. Promote the exception (usually an Optimistic Locking Exception) and convert to a user friendly error.
3. Never allow deletes in the first place. Use a boolean column to indicate delete.
4. Make your application implement Optimistic Locking in sync with your ORM's optimistic locking.
5. Use transactions and/or `synchronized` (single JVM)
6. Use transactions and row locking `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.

In most situations I go with number 2 and/or 3.  Number `5` is the most pessimistic, requires lots of resources with the potential of dead locking.

Answer (score 1):

from what I understand, as far as threads accessing an object, it is a free for all which means both of them may have access to the same object unless synchronization/locking is being used.

From what I am able to gather from your pseudo code, your deletion of the object would completely remove it from the system (including any threads that are accessing it), but I believe it depends on the way you delete it. If you delete an object within the thread itself, it should only delete it from that thread, but if you delete the object outside of the threads it should delete it from the entire system.

From what I see of your code, I am having trouble determining if you are trying to delete the object within Thread B or delete it in the rest of the code, but whichever you are trying to accomplish, I hope my above explanation helps.

Comment: Well, I want to make sure that if any thread performs the delete operation on the `user` object, the object becomes invalidated and other threads having access to it should get notified about the deletion.

Comment: @jaibatrik Its pseudo impossible in Java to pause other threads that way. You either need to have a global lock or a pool of locks or just accept the fact that the data maybe changed in another thread and when you go persist the failure will happen. See my answer.

Comment: Adam Gent is right. You can't just pause other threads that way in Java, but he has given you some ways to work around the issue so definitely give those a shot. @AdamGent I would vote up your answer, but I have not yet acquired the necessary amount of rep. good job though!